# How to process with ABM

Tags: simulation, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

In my bachalar work I am supossed to build an model of terrorist attack in Tokyo in 1995 (sarin gas). I have never done heard anything about ABM until about a month ago. Now I am even able to do some simple models.

However I would welcome some ideas about how to even start with the model. I only need to model one train of 5 from the attack. Should I start with the environment, defining agents...? And is there anybody who could provide me kind of a support if I need to know something?

Also should I model everything with statecharts, or is It possible to model the train with Trail library using flowcharts and passengers with statecharts?

Answer (score 0):

best idea is to check out the example models that come with AnyLogic (Menu/Help/Example Models).

Get a feeling for a good number and start pulling together techniques and items that were used to achieve similar things.

Otherwise, your questions are far too broad for StackOverFlow, I am afraid.

Best modelling advise in a nutshell: Start (super)simple and add features as you go along (and your skills increase)